# JavaScript sort array of object based on the value (conditional sorting)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I've an array like this:

```
[{"category_id":101,"category_name":"abc","state":null},
{"category_id":204,"category_name":"test","state":null},
{"category_id":7,"category_name":"pqr","state":"1526985908122"},
{"category_id":103,"category_name":"User","state":null},
{"category_id":2,"category_name":"System","state":null},
{"category_id":205,"category_name":"xyz","state":"1526985908019"},
{"category_id":203,"category_name":"dash","state":null},
{"category_id":4,"category_name":"hello","state":null},
{"category_id":206,"category_name":"demo","state":"1526985908187"},
{"category_id":6,"category_name":"about","state":null},
{"category_id":3,"category_name":"role","state":null}]
```

I want to sort this array based on the value of state property like you can see state has null and some numeric value here.

If state != null then sort in ascending order and
if state == null then sort in descending order (based on category id)

So the actual result should be like this:

```
[{"category_id":205,"category_name":"xyz","state":"1526985908019"},
{"category_id":7,"category_name":"pqr","state":"1526985908122"},
{"category_id":206,"category_name":"demo","state":"1526985908187"},
{"category_id":204,"category_name":"test","state":null},
{"category_id":203,"category_name":"dash","state":null},
{"category_id":103,"category_name":"User","state":null},
{"category_id":101,"category_name":"abc","state":null},
{"category_id":6,"category_name":"about","state":null},
{"category_id":4,"category_name":"hello","state":null},
{"category_id":3,"category_name":"role","state":null},
{"category_id":2,"category_name":"System","state":null}]
```

So it should sort first 3 records based on state value in ascending order and other records based on null value in descending order based on category id.

This is what I've tried referencing this article:
https://technology.amis.nl/2007/08/24/how-to-fix-your-number-sorting-problems-in-javascript/

```
var ALMOST_ZERO = -0.00000001;  
records.sort(function(a,b){         
    console.log(`comparing ${a.state},${b.state}`);
    var left = a.state != null ? a.state : ALMOST_ZERO;
    var right = b.state != null ? b.state : ALMOST_ZERO;    
    return right-left;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: yes. updated code.

Comment: So what happens when you try that sort function?

Comment: @JJJ: its sorting everything in descending order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a concise version. By using `||`, whenever the upper expression(s) evaluate to 0, it moves on to test the next lower expression:

```js
const arr=[{"category_id":101,"category_name":"abc","state":null},{"category_id":204,"category_name":"test","state":null},{"category_id":7,"category_name":"pqr","state":"1526985908122"},{"category_id":103,"category_name":"User","state":null},{"category_id":2,"category_name":"System",state:null},{"category_id":205,"category_name":"xyz","state":"1526985908019"},{"category_id":203,"category_name":"dash","state":null},{"category_id":4,"category_name":"hello","state":null},{"category_id":206,"category_name":"demo","state":"1526985908187"},{"category_id":6,"category_name":"about","state":null},{"category_id":3,"category_name":"role","state":null}]

arr.sort((a, b) => (
  (a.state === null) - (b.state === null)
  || a.state - b.state
  || b.category_id - a.category_id
));
console.log(arr);
```

Console version:

[image]

ES5 version:

```js
var arr = [{ "category_id": 101, "category_name": "abc", "state": null }, { "category_id": 204, "category_name": "test", "state": null }, { "category_id": 7, "category_name": "pqr", "state": "1526985908122" }, { "category_id": 103, "category_name": "User", "state": null }, { "category_id": 2, "category_name": "System", state: null }, { "category_id": 205, "category_name": "xyz", "state": "1526985908019" }, { "category_id": 203, "category_name": "dash", "state": null }, { "category_id": 4, "category_name": "hello", "state": null }, { "category_id": 206, "category_name": "demo", "state": "1526985908187" }, { "category_id": 6, "category_name": "about", "state": null }, { "category_id": 3, "category_name": "role", "state": null }];

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return (a.state === null) - (b.state === null) || a.state - b.state || b.category_id - a.category_id;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: output is correct but when I'm performing this on chrome console then its not sorting properly

Comment: Works for me in the console.

Comment: it is sorting like this: 205, 2, 206,204,203,7,101,6,4,3,103

Comment: Just checked the response : `typeof(records)` is object. is it because of this??

Comment: Arrays *are* objects. See edit for how it looks in my console; sounds like your issue is elsewhere

Comment: Okay. I'm not using ES15 syntax here: `records.sort(function(a,b){   
 Boolean(b.state) - Boolean(a.state) || a.state - b.state || b.category_id - a.category_id
});
`

Comment: You're not `returning` the result. Use `return Boolean(b.state) - ... ...`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [{
        "category_id": 101,
        "category_name": "abc",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 204,
        "category_name": "test",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 7,
        "category_name": "pqr",
        "state": "1526985908122"
    },
    {
        "category_id": 103,
        "category_name": "User",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 2,
        "category_name": "System",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 205,
        "category_name": "xyz",
        "state": "1526985908019"
    },
    {
        "category_id": 203,
        "category_name": "dash",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 4,
        "category_name": "hello",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 206,
        "category_name": "demo",
        "state": "1526985908187"
    },
    {
        "category_id": 6,
        "category_name": "about",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 3,
        "category_name": "role",
        "state": null
    }
];


var valueWithoutNull = data.filter(val => val.state != null);
var valueWithNull = data.filter(val => val.state == null);

valueWithoutNull = valueWithoutNull.sort((a, b) => a.state - b.state);

var result = [...valueWithoutNull, ...valueWithNull];

console.log(result);
```

```js
var data = [{
        "category_id": 101,
        "category_name": "abc",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 204,
        "category_name": "test",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 7,
        "category_name": "pqr",
        "state": "1526985908122"
    },
    {
        "category_id": 103,
        "category_name": "User",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 2,
        "category_name": "System",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 205,
        "category_name": "xyz",
        "state": "1526985908019"
    },
    {
        "category_id": 203,
        "category_name": "dash",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 4,
        "category_name": "hello",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 206,
        "category_name": "demo",
        "state": "1526985908187"
    },
    {
        "category_id": 6,
        "category_name": "about",
        "state": null
    },
    {
        "category_id": 3,
        "category_name": "role",
        "state": null
    }
];

data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.state == null)
        return 1;
    if (b.state == null)
        return -1;

    return a.state - b.state;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but its not matching with desired output. It should sort state (if not null) in asc and null (if state null) then in desc.

Comment: I updated second option and going to check your concern in first one.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
var arr = [{"category_id":101,"category_name":"abc","state":null},{"category_id":204,"category_name":"test","state":null},{"category_id":7,"category_name":"pqr","state":"1526985908122"},{"category_id":103,"category_name":"User","state":null},{"category_id":2,"category_name":"System",state:null},{"category_id":205,"category_name":"xyz","state":"1526985908019"},{"category_id":203,"category_name":"dash","state":null},{"category_id":4,"category_name":"hello","state":null},{"category_id":206,"category_name":"demo","state":"1526985908187"},{"category_id":6,"category_name":"about","state":null},{"category_id":3,"category_name":"role","state":null}];

arr.sort((a,b) => {
  // If both null, sort by category_id descending
  if(!a.state && !b.state) return b.category_id - a.category_id;
  // if first value is null, swap
  else if(!a.state) return 1;
  // if second value is null, no change 
  else if (!b.state) return -1;
  // if both have values sort by state ascending.
  else return a.state - b.state;
})

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

@sky, try below solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script>
var test= [{"category_id":101,"category_name":"abc","state":null},
{"category_id":204,"category_name":"test","state":null},
{"category_id":7,"category_name":"pqr","state":"1526985908122"},
{"category_id":103,"category_name":"User","state":null},
{"category_id":2,"category_name":"System","state":null},
{"category_id":205,"category_name":"xyz","state":"1526985908019"},
{"category_id":203,"category_name":"dash","state":null},
{"category_id":4,"category_name":"hello","state":null},
{"category_id":206,"category_name":"demo","state":"1526985908187"},
{"category_id":6,"category_name":"about","state":null},
{"category_id":3,"category_name":"role","state":null}];

 function sortByKeyAsc(array, key) {
        return array.sort(function (a, b) {
            var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        });
    }
function sortByKeyDesc(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function (a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x > y) ? -1 : ((x < y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
console.log(sortByKeyDesc(test,"state")  );
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```